# How to list folders containing a file on jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to list folders containing a certain file on jenkins and use later this array.

I read about [`findFiles`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) but I can't find a way to use it in this situation.

The finality is that I need to cd to those folders in a loop and perform some actions.

I have only one jenkins where everything is running

Use case:

I have a workspace in which I have packages. I need to run some commands in some folders, I can't do it from the root of y workspace. They may be in subfolders or subsubfolders. The way I can identify a package is when it contains a `package.xml` (on ROS). Also I don't have any command to list their paths

Comment: Do you want to list on the `master` or `agent`?

Comment: I just updated the description. I have only one machine running everything

Comment: `findFiles` work with current workspace, try `sh()` if you want files outside of current workspace

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish? Please consider reading the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and editing your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's very interesting, I updated the description to add my use case

Comment: Thanks @DavidBensoussan. I think some of the other answers and comments are seeking to understand do you need to run this as an administrative-like task on the `master`, do you need to find some files in a workspace for a run of a job, or possibly something else. It sounds like if you are running a Jenkins pipeline you could use `findFiles`, or `sh`/`dir`, or even write a shell script using something from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171677).

Comment: @mkobit, exactly. Ideally, I would have liked avoiding to have an external script but I ended up doing this. I'm currently waiting a review from colleagues to update the status here.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else is working then you can try running a normal linux command like:

```
folders = sh(
             script: "locate myfile",
             returnStdout: true
                                )
```

Then split this to form an array and use the value like :

```
folders.split("\n")[1]
```

Comment: and don't forget to upvote or accept the answer , I am new and would like that ; )

Comment: sure, i will do

Answer (score 1):

```
def packageDirs = findFiles(glob: '**/package.xml')
    .findAll { f -> !f.directory }
    .collect{ f -> f.path.replace('/', '\\') - ~/\\[^\\]+$/ }

packageDirs.each { d ->
    dir(d) {
        // Process each package here
    }
}
```

Comment: This does't work: all File references run on master, rather than in the actual workspace.

Comment: @MosheZvi that's right, but that was exactly the requirement since David had only one machine. I updated the answer to make it work on any node.